# Saving Mongo array as a Postgres json with AWS Glue

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, pyspark, aws-glue

I am migrating databases from Mongo to Postgres with Glue, however, I encountered a problem with converting an array into a Posgtres json type, because Glue does not have the said datatype. I tried mapping values with a custom function, but no data gets written into my database.
Here is my code.

```
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=DataCatalogtable_node1,
    mappings=[
        ("note", "string", "notes", "string"),
        ("subjects", "array", "subjects", "array"),
        ("createdat", "timestamp", "created_at", "timestamp"),
        ("userid", "string", "user_oid", "string"),
        ("updatedat", "timestamp", "updated_at", "timestamp"),
        ("phonenumber", "string", "phone_number", "string"),
        ("email", "string", "email", "string"),
        ("organizationid", "string", "organization_oid", "string"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
).map(lambda df: df.withColumn("subjects", convert_to_json_array(df.subjects)))
```